# How can I read a single word from a txt file and make it a variable in my code?

Tags: java

I have a text file with a single word say "fish  " but it will have spaces after the word. is there anyway I can pull the word fish as a variable but leave off the spaces?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Have you looked at the methods in the `String` class at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("path_to_file.txt"));
String var = in.next();
var = var.trim();
in.close();
```

Not the most efficient way, but one of the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

string Text = File.ReadAllText("path_to_file.txt").trim();